# Django Haystack: Weird bug with SearchQuerySet

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I ran the following code (on the shell):

```
sqs = SearchQuerySet().models(myModel).filter(title=search_text)
sqs = sqs[:4]

for s in sqs:
    print s.title
```

The weird thing about this code is the following. For most values of *search_text*, this code works fine. When I tried it with a specific *search_text* (namely 'Ca' in my case), I got three results but when it has to print the title of the third result, it says

> 'NoneType' object has no attribube 'title'

If I now run

```
sqs
```

on the shell to see the content of the variable *sqs*, then I see that the third entry is *None*.

Now, if I run the following code (also on the shell):

```
sqs = SearchQuerySet().models(myModel).filter(title=search_text)
sqs
sqs = sqs[:4]
sqs

for s in sqs:
    print s.title
```

I put those intermediate *sqs* just to see the content of it at each step. But then everything is fine, all three results have their title printed.

Is this a Haystack bug? Or a python bug? Or something else?

---

UPDATE: I ran the same code but without

```
sqs = sqs[:4]
```

and everything went fine. So there is something wrong when it tries to resize *sqs*. Oddly enough, whatever goes wrong, doesn't go wrong when I ask python to show its content. (It's like Schrödinger's cat... lol)

Comment: This isn't resizing as it's not a normal list, it's a QuerySet-like object and it gets evaluated when you do a list slice.

Comment: @limelights: Right, but why do I get None sometimes but not always?

Comment: What version of haystack?

Comment: Also, can you post code for the `MyModel` search index?